# Connect an ios app with mysql database

Tags: ios, mysql, swift, web-services, rest

I've a doubt if it is possible connect an ios app using swift directly with a mysql database without a need of a RestAPI.

For example: i have a website with a mysql database and want to make an app that access the data of this base and insert new information there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is incredibly broad.
At a very high level, you need to build an API, REST preferably, that your App can interact with using `NSURLSession` or a 3rd party library.

Comment: but is there a way to connect swift direct with mysql?

Comment: No. Your database is on a server, not on every single phone that will run the app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!